# MongoDB $lookup with max document by date

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I have such a schema for movie

```
{
  "_id" : string,
  "name": string
}
```

and I have such review schema

```
{
  "_id": string,
  "comment": string,
  "date": date,
  "movieId": string
}
```

I want to do $lookup only with review only with the last `date`. One movie can have a lot of reviews so just join and sort by date is not an option. I tried to do `pipeline` but can't figure out how to get the last date.

I want to join by `_id` in movie and `movieId` in review. The output should be like this

```
{
  "_id" : string,
  "name": string,
  "lastReview": [{
      "_id": string,
      "comment": string,
      "date": date,
      "movieId": string
  }]    
}
```

Comment: Do you want to join on latest date? Can u add sample doc and output

Comment: @Gibbs I want to join by `_id` in movie and `movieId` in review. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like following.
Here I used [Uncorrelated-sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to join both collection. We can go the aggregation inside the pipeline of collection. Combination of `Sort` and `limit` gets the latest review.

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "review",
      "let": {
        mid: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $sort: {
            date: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$mid",
                "$movieId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "review"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cFo6bmg3IoQ)

Comment: yeah, it is working. But could you possibly explain how does it build result?  Will it produce a performance degradation on a big number of reviews?

Comment: sure. if you go through the documentation, you will understand how it works. `let` keyword allows to send any data to target collection, and the `pipeline` helps to processing stages the target collection.